# ImportError: No module named IPython.paths when running jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter via: `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -m pip install jupyter`

this install ipython version 4.1.2. However, when I run jupyter notebook, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
ImportError: No module named IPython.paths
```

yet, when I run from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir in the ipython shell directly it works fine. Also when I run /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 and then the same thing, it runs successfully. Additionally, when I check the sys.executable path in python I get `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`

This doesn't make sense to me. How can Ipython and my normal python (both using /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7) both run this successfully, but my jupyter, installed with that specific python, cannot run the command. Any suggestions?

Comment: It appears that for some reason, your `jupyter*` scripts have the OS X system python in their hash-bang, not your locally installed one. You can either edit the first line in those scripts (check and edit the first line of `/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook` ), or start the scripts explicitly with the correct Python executable. For example: `/usr/local/op/python/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook`.

Comment: Also check for an explicitly set PYTHONPATH environment variable. Since these take priority over the default `sys.path`, they may cause problems.

Comment: hmm still same error with /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/jupyter notebook

Comment: I'm partly surprised that your python executable lives in `/usr/local/opt/...`; I think that's a Homebrew thing? Could you check that the relevant site-packages directory (either in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` or in `/usr/local/opt/python/lib/pyhton2.7` contains the `notebook` directory?

Comment: Also, in your normal Python shell, what is `sys.path`? And outside it, what is `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: What about if you do `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook` (note dash in jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Just now this helped me. Someone might find this useful.

```
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
ImportError: No module named IPython.paths
```

So I was running Python 3 on Linux mint 17. I first uninstalled jupyter from my system using the command.

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall jupyter
```

After successfully uninstalling I installed jupyter again with the following command.

```
sudo -H pip3 install jupyter
```

And when I launched jupyter again using

```
jupyter notebook
```

The `kernel` didn't die or didn't restart. Everything works fine now. I hope atleast one person finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade ipython:

```
pip install ipython==5.3.0
```

If you cannot uninstall ipython, try this:

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed -U ipython==5.3.0
```