# how dcan i install Ipython.paths, so that the jupyter notebook kernel works?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

Following a Python course, I had to install Jupyter,

but when opening a new python3 project from the browser page, i get this pop up message :

> Dead kernel
>
> The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. It is
>   possible the kernel cannot be restarted. If you are not able to
>   restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook, but
>   running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened.

on the terminal, here is what comes up :

```
WARNING:root:kernel 3103f319-5721-4b62-98b0-649dcc448421 restarted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 14, in <module>
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
ImportError: No module named 'IPython.paths'
[W 01:24:38.987 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 01:24:38.988 NotebookApp] Kernel 3103f319-5721-4b62-98b0-649dcc448421 died, removing from map.
ERROR:root:kernel 3103f319-5721-4b62-98b0-649dcc448421 restarted failed!
[W 01:24:42.242 NotebookApp] Kernel deleted before session
[W 01:24:42.243 NotebookApp] 410 DELETE /api/sessions/396ef2da-3d1d-4416-a959-45500e346b2a (127.0.0.1) 3.83ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled4.ipynb?kernel_name=python3
[I 01:26:23.898 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Untitled4.ipynb
```

I tried installing the IPython.paths, running

```
pip3 install paths
```

but this is what I get :

```
Collecting paths
  Downloading paths-0.0.1a1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qppr67p0/paths/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        from paths import metadata
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qppr67p0/paths/paths/__init__.py", line 31
        print type(filename)
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qppr67p0/paths/
```

I've tried to review various threads, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166556/importerror-no-module-named-ipython-paths-when-running-jupyter-notebook) 
, but none seemed to be exactely what I'm looking for...
Thanks for your help

Comment: ok seemed un Ipkernel update was all that was needed...
PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: Could you pls tell how you updated ipkernel? I tried pip3 install --upgrade ipkernel, "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipkernels ( from versions:) No matching distribution found for ipkernels